# Writing to file from console produces whitespace

Tags: assembly, file-io, x86, whitespace, irvine32

Im trying to write to a file through the console using `ReadString` that saves to `buffer` which would be used to call `WriteToFile`. Doing so writes the text correctly in the correct order but it also writes the remaining whitespace.

ie. a 4 character word and 46 white spaces assuming `SIZEOF buffer` = 50

How would I get around this and just write the text with no white space and a delimiter? Im also intending to call `readfromfile` and go through the words one at a time and see if they match a other word using `str_compare`.

I tried using `Str_trim` on the buffer but had no luck

**Code below**

```
include Irvine32.inc
Include macros.inc

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

BUFFER_SIZE = 50

.data

filename BYTE 80 DUP(?)
fileHandle HANDLE ?
buffer BYTE BUFFER_SIZE DUP(?)

char BYTE ' '

.code
main proc

; create file to write to

mWrite "Enter filename: "
mov edx, OFFSET filename
mov ecx, SIZEOF filename
call ReadString

mov edx, OFFSET filename
call CreateOutputFile
mov fileHandle, eax

; write to output file

mov edx, OFFSET buffer
mov ecx, SIZEOF buffer
mWrite "Enter student identification number: "
call ReadString

INVOKE Str_trim, ADDR buffer, char

mov eax, fileHandle
mov edx, OFFSET buffer
mov ecx, SIZEOF buffer
call WriteToFile

mov edx, OFFSET buffer
mov ecx, SIZEOF buffer
mWrite "Enter student first name and lastname: "
call ReadString

INVOKE Str_trim, ADDR buffer, char

mov eax, fileHandle
mov edx, OFFSET buffer
mov ecx, SIZEOF buffer
call WriteToFile

mov edx, OFFSET buffer
mov ecx, SIZEOF buffer
mWrite "Enter student date of birth: "
call ReadString

INVOKE Str_trim, ADDR buffer, char

mov eax, fileHandle
mov edx, OFFSET buffer
mov ecx, SIZEOF buffer
call WriteToFile
    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

If perhaps I don't make any sense at all I included the problem I am working on

> Write a program that creates a new text file. Prompt the user for a
>   student identification number, last name, first name, and date of
>   birth. Write this information to the file. Input a total of 10 records
>   in the same manner and close the file.
>
> Ask user to enter first name, last name and date of birth. Based on
>   these inputs, search the text file and print "Match" if the input
>   record exists and print "NotFound" if the input record does not exist.

Comment: Does ReadString return a length?  If so use that, otherwise use strlen or some other length as a length for WriteToFile instead  `mov ecx, SIZEOF buffer`.  Obviously that function just writes as many bytes as you tell it to.

Comment: Turns out it does so I shoved eax in ebx directly after ```ReadString``` since eax will be occupied by ```fileHandle```. Then moves ebx to ecx for ```WriteToFile```.

Although I feel like ```Str_trim``` should work somehow

Comment: `Str_trim` only removes trailing chars from a 0-terminated C string by replacing the first one with a `0` byte https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~acpang/course/asm_2004/slides/chapt_09.pdf.  If you still `write` the whole buffer to the file, all the other whitespace is still there, plus the zero byte.  `WriteToFile` deals with explicit-length buffers so it's always going to write as much as you tell it, regardless of there being a `0` somewhere in there.  It's like C `fwrite`; that's why you have to pass it a length arg instead of it scanning the string for a `0`.

Comment: thanks for the help